# GRASS v.clean gives weird results

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, grass-gis

I have the following yellow line layer and I would expect the v.clean tool to split my lines at each intersection. Running the tool gives me the red lines. The settings are all on default. Why is that, and how can I change it? Is there perhaps a detailed tutorial on the tool I haven't found yet?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the [manual page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/v.clean.html)?

Comment: yes but it just says that the break tool breaks lines at intersections and thats it.

I created a new Line layer with intersections and tried to use it again and now the tool creates a new line layer with no objects at all. 

Perhabs someone else hat that problem before?

Comment: What settings are you using?  You might try different snap tolerances and tool thresholds.

Comment: Make sure the _Do not build topology for output vector_ option is unchecked. Tick on and uncheck it. Please be a little more specific. Your input layer is LineString or MultiLineString geometries type? What is the name of the output layer, _Cleaned_ or _Errors_? What version of QGIS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be something you can solve tweaking the `threshold` and `type` settings while `snap`ping:

From the `v.clean` [documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/v.clean.html)

> tool=snap
>   The snap tool snaps vertices to another vertex not farther away than thresh. If there is no other vertex within thresh, no snapping will be done. 
>   The **type** option can have a strong influence on the result. 
>   A too large threshold and **type**=boundary can severely damage area topology, beyond repair.

Try using a low `threshold` value:

> threshold=float[,float,...] 
>   Threshold in map units, one value for each
>   tool Default: 0.0[,0.0,...])

and/or a different `type`:

> type=string[,string,...]
>   Input feature type
>   Options: point, line, boundary, centroid, area, face, kernel
>   Default: point,line,boundary,centroid,area,face,kernel